# Badge suggestion: HATER, LOVER, and FAIR AND BALANCED

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badge-request, negative-badges

I wanted to suggest three new badges:

- **HATER**: If you've downvoted any one person more than 20 times.
- **LOVER**: If you've upvoted any one person more than 20 times.
- **FAIR AND BALANCED**: If you've upvoted *AND* downvoted one person more 20 times UP and DOWN.

What do you think? Then we would finally know what type of people we have on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Disregarding any implications of the "encouragement" the badges offer, you do realize that it is not difficult at all for most people to get all 3 badges and therefore thwart your intent on highlighting the different classes of people, aye?

Comment: @Grace, No, because you can get them more than once. So you could still be a **HATER** three times, and a **LOVER** only once, and *still* not be **FAIR AND BALANCED**

Comment: `+1` great idea - I think you should get Exp for earning the **LOVER** badge, and lose Exp for getting the **HATER** badge.

Comment: Someone's been watching too much Fox News.

Comment: @Ether: [We need to do a penetrating expose of the people on SO to find out if they are pro-unicorn or anti-unicorn.](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2008/10/17/gop-rep-channels-mccarthy_n_135735.html)

Comment: Badges are intended to encourage desirable behavior. What desirable behavior do these badges encourage?

Comment: They encourage involvement by presenting a visual indicator of fun statistics, this clearly has value and it is the badge's raison d'être

Comment: That could be said about nearly anything. They don't appear to specifically encourage any kind of desirable behavior.

Comment: Neither do Tax Refunds.

Comment: Yeah, that made a lot of sense.

Comment: @Lord.Quackstar, look how much "reputation" I've got since you made the comment. And, I haven't changed a thing. See, the swarms of people that would have the HATER badge have dwindled and a new group of unbiased non-partisans have come to see what the suggestion was about.

Comment: I think these badges encourage serial voting. Votes toward these badges would be reversed, at which point the badge is removed. Therefore, a person who wants such a badge would keep serially voting others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: Why would we add a badge designed to encourage serial voting?

Comment: This sounds more like a rant, than a reasonable feature request. Did you feel you've been personally targeted by votes? It's unlikely a single person is going to downvote all of your posts, and if so that's usually tracked, and would be rolled back.

Comment: Also, if that's proposed to be a badge group, how should bronze, silver and gold actually be applied?

Comment: Yeah sure, and also show which user you downvoted, right? Great way to make people love SE and each other.

Comment: Here's my downvote for copying the content and idea from someone else's post. AKA plagiarism.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні might also be a sock.

Answer (score 142):

You should vote on a *post*, not a *person*. If you vote based on the person, you're doing it wrong. And we don't want badges encouraging people to do it wrong.

Comment: I'm not suggesting people vote on a person. I'm suggesting we give a badge as an indicator of the way people vote.

Comment: And what will these badges *indicate* to us? Absolutely nothing. I know that I upvote certain people a lot just because I'm active in a niche tag with them and they post many useful answers, not because I have a super nice personality or I'm obsessed with them or I'm a sock-puppet of theirs (*quick sideways glances*).

Comment: Enough with the sock puppet hate!

Answer (score 39):

The badge system is designed to promote desired behavior within the system and I do not believe encouraging users (implicitly or explicitly) to think about **who** they are voting for should be done in any way. Voting should be based on the quality of the question or answer being voted on.

Comment: Don't think about it, if you get the **LOVER** that's just good.. If you get the **HATER** that's just bad... They're just visual indicators of the personality.

Comment: The badge system is not intended to provide visual indicators of the person's personality, it is to encourage desired behavior in the system.

Comment: What about the old woot badge? It was ment to encourage desired behavoir in the system about users that used woot.com?

Comment: The "Woot" badge was actually just the Enthusiast badge in an advertising disguise. Enthusiast encourages visiting the site, Woot was simply sponsoring it for a short period.

Comment: Unfortunately, some people downvote for the smallest reasons. -1  looks disgusting. **How good your rating is depends on who is browsing the forum at that moment.** If you're unlucky, you get caught by voting sadists.

Answer (score 12):

This site is about posts, not people so we really shouldn't be encouraging targetting of individuals like that. That's only one small step from [serial-voting, which is not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).

Hater is pretty insulting to people who are trying to keep poor quality posts off the site and if you're posting poor quality questions, either you should recognise that and improve or expect to be stopped by the system.

If you've posted 20 terrible questions, why shouldn't you be downvoted? What's hateful about quality control? Do you really think we want more bad posts to stick around or even more people to have to pointlessly read them because someone's worried about getting an badge named hater?

Comment: Is every SE vote a measure of objectivity and quality? There have been innumerable cases where one user takes a strong dislike to a novice or veteran user and will, regardless of quality, downvote almost every contribution submitted by that person. Moreover, we don't live in a world where people's emotions are divorced from constructive criticisms: feelings of hurt, embarrassment, anger, confusion and pride are difficult to overcome and acknowledge except for the most stoic among us. I see hi-rep users on ELL getting very tetchy when they get a downvote and/or a valid criticism.

Comment: "This site is about posts, not people" No, it's about people who have experience and knowledge who answer other people's questions. If you insist that people don't count for anything only their contributions do, then why do we have a rep system in the first place? It's so the community (made up by people) can recognise and hopefilly, respect the people behind that rep.

Comment: What I mean is that it doesn't matter who posts the content, it's the content that's posted that we rate, not the person who posts it.

Answer (score 9):

None of those badges should be added because it undermines what it means to upvote or downvote.

Answer (score 4):

I sat down and thought about this for a bit, and decided that it wouldn't really add or detract anything.  Over time (as this thread is 2 years old), you would likely upvote or downvote any given user enough times to earn all three badges.  At first I thought it might discourage serial downvoting, but then it kind of makes sense if someone posts a lot that eventually you might upvote 20 of their posts and downvote another 20.  That wouldn't necessarily make you a LOVER, a HATER or FAIR & BALANCED, it's just natural that over an extended period of time that you would eventually earn all of those badges.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the point of responding to this?  The question is three years old, and is clearly status-declined.

Comment: @LBT - Someone recently serial-downvoted Evan, as was pointed out in his answer in this thread: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196634/what-is-considered-bad-reputation-on-stack-overflow/196642#196642.  It led me here, and I didn't even realize it was an old question until after I answered it.  I don't always look at dates.  It DID get me a few HATERS, though!  :o)

Comment: He didn't get serially-downvoted, he got downvoted by a boatload of people because he's a known troll who does obnoxious things like calling repuation "experience", coming up with crackpot conspiracy theories, has been repeatedly comment- and question-banned yet somehow manages to stay unsuspended.

Comment: Oh. Hmmpf. His answers don't really seem all that "troll-like", although admittedly I didn't read everything he's posted. I'm still perplexed that my answer, which I thought was well thought out and makes perfect sense, received 3 downvotes so far. @shrugs@

Comment: @JohnnyBones Guilty by association! These are the kinds of people who would throw the baby out and save the bathwater to drown more babies in.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - You actually referred to reputation as (@gasp@) "experience"?!?  Sweet Jesus in a burning bush, you are one evil bastage!

Comment: @JohnnyBones Considering the vast majority of them are deleted, no, they don't look "troll-like." You're only seeing the decent ones that didn't warrant deletion.